# How to calculate the expected % of the task given the start date, the end date and TODAY ()?

Tags: task

ow to calculate the expected % of the task given the start date, the end date and TODAY ()?

Answer (score 0):

You have to calculate how many days have passed from starting day untill today. Then multiply it with 100 then divide the result with the whole task time

(TODAY - START DATE ) *100 / (END DATE - START DATE )